# Deciding CL-IS on graph efficiently

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms

Given an arbitrary graph $G$, could there be a polynomial time algorithm to tell if it has a larger size clique $(\omega(G))$ or larger independence number$(\alpha(G))$?

Comment: So you are asking whether the decision problem of whether $\omega(G) < \alpha(G)$ is in P?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon yes apparently it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take an abitrary instance of the independent set problem: given an $n$-vertex graph $H=(V,E)$ and an integer $k\ge1$, does $H$ contain an independent set on $k$ vertices.

Construct a new graph $G$ that is the disjoint union of graph $H$, a clique $C$ on $n+k$ vertices and an independent set $I$ on $n$ vertices.
Note that $\omega(G)=n+k$.

- If $H$ contains an independent set on $k$ vertices, then $\alpha(G)\ge n+k+1$.
  You may use the $k$-element independent set in $G$, the $n$ vertices in $I$, and one vertex from $C$.
- If $H$ does not contain an independent set on $k$ vertices, then $\alpha(G)\le n+k$.

Hence by comparing $\omega(G)$ and $\alpha(G)$, you can answer arbitrary instances of the NP-hard independent set problem.